Outward unit normal of the Superegg
I´m working with a tube-like object in 3D, which consists of a cylinder of radius $B$ at center $(x_0, y_0)$ with height $L-H$, this is glued together from above with a superegg with the same radius and with height $H$, which has the equation: $$f(x,y,z):=\frac{|\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}|^p}{B^p}+\left|\frac{z-(L-H)}{H}\right|^p-1=0 $$
$p$ simply determines the degree of flattening.
See an image of it below.

I´m trying to calculate the unit outward normal of the superegg, but the result I got, doesn't look orthogonal to the tangent space of the surface (cf. red arrow in the image).
My attempt:
I transfer my system to cylindrical coordinates, and any point $(x,y,z)$ on the super egg, can be written as $(r\cos(\theta)+x_0, r\sin(\theta)+y_0, H\cdot \sqrt[p]{1-|\frac{r}{B}|^p}+L-H)$ for some $r\in (0, B], \theta \in [0, 2\pi)$
Then if I compute the gradient of $f$ at these coordinates I get
$$
\nabla f(x,y,z)=p\cdot\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{B^p}\cos(\theta)\cdot r^{p-1}\\
\frac{1}{B^p}\sin(\theta)\cdot r^{p-1}\\
\frac{1}{H}\left(1-|\frac{r}{B}|^p\right)^{1-\frac{1}{p}}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
to obtain the unit outward normal, I divide by its norm, and that´s the red line you can see on the picture.
Any help pointing out my mistake is appreciated, thank you!

Did you use the right formula for gradient in cylindrical coordinates? Why do you need to use cylindrical coordinates, when the gradient is pretty easy to do in $x, y, z$ coordinates?

The derivative w.r.t $x,y,z$ would be $$\nabla f(x,y,z)=(\frac{p}{B^p}(x-x_0)((x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2)^{\frac{p}{2}-1}, \frac{p}{B^p}(y-y_0)((x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2)^{\frac{p}{2}-1}, \frac{p}{H^p}(z-(L-H))^{p-1}).$$
If I then insert the vector in polar coordinates as above, then I get the gradient I provided in my question. I want to work with polar coordinates because it makes further computations simpler.

The gradient seems correct, so the unit outward normal should be correct.

@Kakashi Thank you, I double checked it myself aswell, but still didn't find the mistake. Maybe it just looks weird in matplotlib, or I made a mistake plotting it.
